My custom Outlook add-in only works for Classic Outlook
So I am making a custom outlook add-in. It is fairly simple. When the recipients field when composing an email contains a specific email the subject and body are populated with a certain template. I used the yeoman generator to create the add-in and it seems to work fine in classic outlook. But when trying to open the add-in in the new or web outlook the taskpane does not open.
The console and network dont seem to show anything and the add-in doesnt load. I have tried the typical troubleshooting such as making sure the dev server im using is using https and the certificate served is valid and the dependencies are supported but the add-in seems to just fail to initiate in any version of outlook besides outlook classic. Has anyone else had this issue or additional troubleshooting steps I can try?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
